# Iterative matrix inversion with $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

The usual conjugate gradient type algorithms for iteratively finding the inverse of a matrix applied to a vector, $x = A^{-1} y$, works by minimizing $\|Ax - y\|^2$ where $\| \cdot \|$ is the $L^2$-norm. The stopping criterion is usually $\|Ax - y\| < \varepsilon \|y\|$ with some small $\varepsilon$.

Is there an efficient algorithm if I'm interested in the same problem but using the $L^p$-norm for the stopping criterion?

I've actually found some papers with $1 \leq p \leq 2$, but I'd need large $p$, more precisely what I'm really interested in is the $L^\infty$-norm. Are there efficient algorithms for $L^\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to solve the optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\min_x\quad \|Ax-y\|_\infty.
\end{equation*}
This is a nonsmooth optimization problem, but is amenable to a variety of scalable optimization techniques, for instance, [Nesterov's smooth minimization of non-smooth functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-004-0552-5). Of course, the above problem can also be cast as a linear program, and thus solved more accurately using interior point methods.

**However**, if you meant that you wish to minimize $\|Ax-y\|_2$, while ensuring that $\|Ax-y\|_\infty \le \delta\|y\|_\infty$, then you have at your hands a [second order cone program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming), for which there are interior point methods, as well as other more scalable methods.

Comment: I'm interested in the former. Nesterov's method looks great, but how would this be cast as a linear program and then solved using interior point methods (as you suggested)?

Comment: Check out chapters 3-4 of Boyd and Vandenberghe (Convex Optimization); that'll cover such a problem and show how to introduce new variables and constraints to help reformulate this as an LP.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Suvrit's answer, from chapter 6 of [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/):

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

As a shameless plug for my own work: As you want to use the $\infty$-norm as a stopping criterion, you may be interested in *homotopy* methods. For the sake of completeness, assume that you want to find *sparse* approximate solutions to $Ax=b$. You set a tolerance $\delta= \|b\|_\infty$ and see that $x_\delta = 0$ is the sparsest $x$ that solves $Ax=b$ up to the tolerance $\delta$ (in the $\infty$-norm). A homotopy method starts from this $x_\delta$ and $\delta$ and reduces the value of $\delta$ while keeping $x_\delta$ a solution of (in this case)
$$
\min_x \|x\|_1\quad\text{s.t.}\quad\|Ax-b\|_\infty\leq\delta.
$$
It can be shown that the path $\delta\mapsto x_\delta$ is piecewise linear and that one can calculate the whole path by solving a number of very small linear programs. On top of that, consecutive linear programs that have to be solved are very similar to that a specialized algorithm that takes this into account can be made faster than commercial LP solvers. We describe the method in the paper ["A Primal-Dual Homotopy Algorithm for $\ell^1$-Minimization with $\ell^∞$-Constraints"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.10022).

I suspect that a similar method could be derived for minimal 2-norm approximate solutions but I am not sure if the method could be made fast.